# Typescript compiler error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I have installed the visual studio 2015 and then started to compile the angular 2 project... But while compiling it shows an error like this,

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TypeScriptHTMLApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(102,5): 
       error : Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools 
       than is currently installed on this machine.  
       No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe.  
       You may be able to fix this problem by changing the <TypeScriptToolsVersion> 
        element in your project file.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(102,5): 
      error MSB6004: The specified task executable location 
       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe" is invalid
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It clearly indicates that the 'Typescript Compiler' you installed is different than the one that is used in your project. Try upgrading it.

Comment: Hi Asker..That's what i'm asking... how to change the typescript compiler version

Comment: First option- check this article -  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html  Second option - try to install nuget packages Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild